# Windows 7 and XP dual boot - resizing partitions on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, multi-boot

I've just installed Win7 on my laptop and it is dual-booting with my Windows XP.

I just realized that I should have added more space to Win7 as I will slowly abandon XP.

My question is: Is it safe to resize the partitions (currently there's a single partition for each OS) in Win7? 
Will XP continue working correctly?

Pablo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's reasonably safe but you are best taking a backup first. Also it's worth defragmenting your xp partition before you start. If win 7 won't cope with the resize try a gparted live cd, it gives you a fairly friendly gui and seems to succeed more often.

Answer (score 0):

You might lose some of files in XP, so just back it up, otherwise, you should be fine.

Comment: you mean like they will be just gone? I'd thought it copies 100% or nothing...